# convert input string to char* <Bad Ptr>

Tags: c++, access-violation, cin

the problem is my console application gets a string from user:

```
string input;
cin >> input;
```

Now I want to convert this string to char* and then pass it to a function:

```
char *argument = NULL;
argument = (char *) input.c_str();
```

my function is declared as :

```
int function (char *input, char *output)
```

I've got access violation when debug this code, so I tried to define everything:

```
strcpy(argument, input.c_str());
```

but again I've got access violation and Bad Ptr!!
any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
argument = (char *) input.c_str(); 
           ^^^^^^^^ you don't need this. further c_str() returns a "const pointer to char"
                    not "pointer to char". 

int function (char *input, char *output)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^|________ It should be "string input" or "string &input"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that c_str() returns a `const char*`, not a `char*`. You are not allowed to modify any characters in the character sequence returned by c_str().

So you need to:

```
const char *argument = input.c_str();
```

Your compiler would have caught this error if you didn't do the cast in:

```
argument = (char *) input.c_str();
```

Without the cast:

```
argument = input.c_str();
```

it would not have compiled (or perhaps it would have compiled, but with a big, fat warning attached to it).

Furthermore, if you later modify `input`, the pointer you got from c_str() is no longer valid and accessing it will also result in undefined behavior.

If you want to have a `char*` version of the string, then you should copy it:

```
char *argument = new char[input.length() + 1];
std::strcpy(argument, input.c_str());
```

Do not forget to free `argument` when you no longer need it:

```
delete[] argument;
```

Comment: so what should I do? I don't have access to my function code and I call it from a dll, how can I pass input string from console application to {char *} argument of function